# Configure firewall under Win7 for different interfaces command line

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-7, firewall, netsh

Im looking forward to configure my firewall under windows 7 for different interfaces throught a .bat file using netsh
In Win XP netsh has the parameter "interface" which allow me to specify the interface that I intend to enable the firewall for it, the opening ports for it...
In windows 7 the parameter interface is not supported anymore.
Any idea on how can I deal with it ?

Thank you very much for the help

Comment: This looks like a good question for [SuperUser](https://SuperUser.com).

Comment: To be more precise on my first question this command does not run in Win7 anymore: echo firewall set opmode mode=disable interface="LAN" |netsh (this command works well on windows xp) I want to disable firewall for a specific interface. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested, i found a solution to my problem with vbscript :

```
option explicit

Const NET_FW_PROFILE2_DOMAIN = 1
Const NET_FW_PROFILE2_PRIVATE = 2
Const NET_FW_PROFILE2_PUBLIC = 4

Dim fwPolicy2
Dim InterfaceArray

Set fwPolicy2 = CreateObject("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2")

InterfaceArray = Array("LAN")

fwPolicy2.ExcludedInterfaces(NET_FW_PROFILE2_DOMAIN) = InterfaceArray
fwPolicy2.ExcludedInterfaces(NET_FW_PROFILE2_PRIVATE) = InterfaceArray
fwPolicy2.ExcludedInterfaces(NET_FW_PROFILE2_PUBLIC) = InterfaceArray
```

-> my interface's name is LAN, if you want to disable firewall for many interfaces, just add them to the array : Array ("LAN1", "LAN2", ...). You can choose the profile on which you want to disable the firewall : domain, public or private